# How to deploy react application as a single file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-deployment

React web application is not familiar to me. However I have to build and deploy to a server.

According to others, I have to so something like...

1. compress whole react project with tar
2. upload tar to the server
3. `npm install` - `npm run compile`(doing some action which stated in `webpack.config.js`) - `npm start`

However, it looks weird to me. Our java project build output is 60MB, but front end source is almost like 700MB.

```
Added some extra opinion.
The size of  the project is...

- original node project
- include webpack output directory
- npm module directory and build directory

Anyway, I can not get why do I still need the original source code?
I already have build output file
```

Further more, why should `npm install` in the target server? - So I think this(using tar) is not a good way to deploy a react web application.

So I would like to know proper way to deploy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me starting with a scaffolding code generated by the create-react-app works well. You might want to use it 
 - https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

It is not clear to me too, why the front-end would be "700" MB. Presuming you are building a single page application or similar, the development and deployment work-flow looks similar to -

1. Development

   - Get node installed (eventually installing npm) on development machine.
   - Get create-react-app installed using npm.
   - Get a react app created using 'create-react-app' commandline.
   - From inside of the app-directory giving command 'npm start' to start a development server serving your application.
   - Changing the source-code to build your app.
2. Deployment

   - When application is deploy-ready. From inside the app directory, giving command 'npm run build' makes ready-to-serve files in the configurable build directory(usually - build).
   - To deploy just compress and/or distribute the directory itself.

One clear thing to notice here is that you don't need node and/or npm to run the built source code. You need them while you are developing the application. The reason primarily is because build process creates a bundle of all the needed JS and packs with the application. Also, you don't have to worry about any things like web-pack etc., at-least while deploying.

A few references(courtesy: google) to point in right direction -

- https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-deployment-5a717d4378fd
- https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#creating-a-new-application
- https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#adding-react-to-an-existing-application

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact setup but the most common way is to build the application locally and push the compiled files to the server. Webpack compiles everything in single file and dependent of your application and Webpack configuration it will save it in one JavaScript file.

At the end you only need a webserver which can serve static files. So no need to run `npm start` which is most of the time a development server.